# Wordpress Search Query

Tags: wordpress, search, phpmyadmin

I wat to use existing wordpress database with my own custom php script but got problem with search result.
How to search using phpmyadmin sql with wordpress search query?

Comment: What is the problem and [what have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I need sql query just like wordpress search query to search keyword on database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it using var_dump(get_defined_vars()) in search.php file

for search keyword I love to learn php the sql is

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%i%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%i%')) AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%love%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%love%')) AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%to%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%to%')) AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%learn%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%learn%')) AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%php%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%php%')))  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [$wpdb object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to create custom queries.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but it is worth bearing in mind that most queries can be handled with a WordPress function, try Googling what you want to achieve.

Comment: I mean manual sql query (SELECT * FROM ...) but the result exactly like wordpress search result